# How to set persistent cookies that stay even after closing window?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set cookies that have to be persistent even if the user closes the browser.

document.cookie = `name=${generateString()}`; 'expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';

But when I close the window, and I open it again there is no cookie saved.

My goal is to save somehow the current user without him/her being logged and create a temporary user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). For example:

```
// setting an item with name "expires"
localStorage.setItem('expires', 'Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC');

// retrieving the item
const expires = localStorage.getItem('expires');
```

Comment: trying to store the session on a mongodb is more complicated, right? will try with localStorage.

Comment: These things are fundamentally different.

Cookies or localStorage happen on the client-side. You are saving something in the browser of the user's machine. The client does not even know about MongoDB, that would be something that you have on your server side. By the way, the user can of course always delete anything that you are storing in his browser. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage) might help you understand better.

Comment: daudprobst yes, i was overlappying the two things and I guess I was trying to make things difficult. thanks for the guidance and the sources given.